# Bash Script : Read a file containing IP and run script

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have created a useradd script in bash which is running manually(ive to copy script on remote host and run the script).

i want that script to read a host.txt file,where ill mention the ip's on which it must run by login into the remote host

```
#!/bin/bash

# Unlock the crtical directory for modification

chattr -i /etc/passwd
chattr -i /etc/shadow
chattr -i /etc/group
chattr -i /etc/gshadow
chattr -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#Script to Add User

read -p 'Please Enter The Username To Add: ' name
echo "$name" > /tmp/userlist.txt
clear
echo -e "Hello $name\nYour Name Is Added To The List."
userfile=/tmp/userlist.txt
username=$(cat /tmp/userlist.txt | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z')
for user in $username
do
useradd $user -N -s /bin/bash
usermod -aG sudo $user
passwd $user
echo "AllowUsers ${user}" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config                   \\Prefix the line with # if username is hard coded
#sed -i 's/tui/tui <hard coded username>/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config                        \\remove # if the user is hard coded
#sed -i 's/<hard coded username>.*<hard coded username>/<hard coded username>/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config       \\remove # if the user is hard coded
#sed -i 's/tui/tui <hard coded username>/g' /etc/security/access.conf                       \\remove # if the user is hard coded
done
echo "=================================="

echo "User $name Have Been Created."

echo "=================================="
tail /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f1

#lock the crtical directory for modification

chattr +i /etc/passwd
chattr +i /etc/shadow
chattr +i /etc/group
chattr +i /etc/gshadow
chattr +i /etc/ssh/sshd_config
systemctl restart ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a file of IP's called ip.txt

```
while IFS= read -r dest; do
  scp useradd.sh "root@$dest:remote/path/"
  ssh root@$dest "/bin/bash remote/path/useradd.sh"
done <ip.txt
```

If root is not available to login (recommended) then substitute with the correct user and than add sudo to the command.

This assumes the login is done via a key file and does not have a password.

If the file is already on the host then skip the scp stage - or you can use xargs like

```
cat ip.txt | xargs -I{} ssh user@{} sudo remote/path/useradd.sh
```

Or - I can recommend using ansible.

Comment: I want to run the script on local machine also the host.txt will be kept on local machine

Comment: OK so the first part of the answer should work for you. That script runs on your local machine, copies your useradd script to the server using scp and runs it with ssh. Let me know how you get on.